# Which is correct and idiomatic, "irregular-verb appearance", "appearance of irregular verbs", or "irregular verbal appearance"?

Tags: nouns, hyphens, attributive-nouns

Which is the most correct and idiomatic? I think that 1. and 2. are pretty correct and idiomatic, but 3. is just erroneous.

1. The irregular-verb appearance is very interesting.
2. The appearance of irregular verbs is very interesting.
3. The irregular verbal appearance is very interesting.

Comment: Opinion: the first makes it seem as if the subject is an independent agent, like a character who shows up. The second is more idiomatic, but perhaps as "The occurrence of irregular verbs is very interesting."

Comment: You may find this advice about asking questions useful: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Comment: What do you mean by appearance?

Comment: Is this one okay *The irregular-verb occurrence is very interesting* ?

Answer (score 0):

The term "*irregular verb*":  is not usually hyphenated. In your Sentence 1 it seems as if you are discussing the physical appearance of such a verb, not when an instance of it occurs. Your sentence 2 is probably the closest to natural of any of the three, but even it sounds odd to me. I would suggest something like:

> It is interesting that irregular verbs occur.

Or a variant that gives more detail, perhaps.